# Change the elements position with the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove',  moveMouse)
function moveMouse(params) {
    const clientX = params.clientX;
    const clientY = params.clientY;
    const square = document.querySelector('.square');
    square.style.left = clientX + 'px';
    square.style.top = clientY + 'px';
}
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const p = document.createElement("div");
    p.classList.add('square');
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    container.appendChild(p);
})
```

```css
.square {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-72%,-72%);
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

With the code above i want to apply the `moveMouse` function on all elements which i create by clicking. Now that function is working only for the first element ( the `div` with the class `.square`); How to apply the `moveMouse` function and for the next created elements by clicking?

Comment: `document.querySelector` will only ever get you _one_ element at most. If you want to select multiple elements, then you need to use `querySelectorAll`, and then loop over the elements you get returned, to set your CSS properties on each one of them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` and loop through the elemtns to change their position :

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove',  moveMouse)
function moveMouse(params) {
    const clientX = params.clientX;
    const clientY = params.clientY;
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
    squares.forEach(sq => {
      sq.style.left = clientX + 'px';
      sq.style.top = clientY + 'px';
    });    
}
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const p = document.createElement("div");
    p.classList.add('square');
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    container.appendChild(p);
})
```

```css
.square {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-72%,-72%);
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```